# Refactor to smaller function, how?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a function that loads a large selectlist for ASP.NET MVC.
This functions has a methodsize of 354 rows.
I want to refactor to more functions or to a local field so that each function will be less than 40 lines.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static SelectList CreateShutterSpeedList()
        {
            var shutterSpeedList = new List<CameraSettingItem>();

            var secNotationPostfix = "\"";

            shutterSpeedList.Add(new CameraSettingItem
            {
                Id = ShutterSpeedDefaultValue,
                Description = string.Empty
            });

            shutterSpeedList.Add(new CameraSettingItem
            {
                Id = 1,
                Description = "30" + secNotationPostfix
            });

etc
```

Maybe a private list as a variable ? Or loading from file ? Or else...?

Comment: Create a delegate for adding to that list and call the delegate with parameters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improving working code does not belong to Stackoverflow but http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TimSchmelter and PartickPeters: Please note that we would need the full function's code for Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If IDs above `ShutterSpeedDefaultValue` are assigned sequentially, you could create an array of descriptions first, and then convert it to `CameraSettingItem` list with LINQ:

```
var descriptions = new[] {
    string.Empty
,   "30" + secNotationPostfix
,   ...
};
shutterSpeedList = descriptions
    .Select((d,i) => new CameraSettingItem {
        Id = i==0 ? ShutterSpeedDefaultValue : i
    ,   Description = d
    })
    .ToList();
```

You could also create a list of `CameraSettingItem`s outside of your method's body, like this:

```
private const string secNotationPostfix = "\"";

private static IList<CameraSettingItem> shutterSpeedList = new List<CameraSettingItem> {
    new CameraSettingItem {
        Id = ShutterSpeedDefaultValue,
        Description = string.Empty
    },
    new CameraSettingItem {
        Id = 1,
        Description = "30" + secNotationPostfix
    },
    ...
};

public static SelectList CreateShutterSpeedList() {
    return new SelectList(shutterSpeedList, "Id", "Description");
}
```

Comment: The Id's are not sequentially....

I currently have private array:

public static CameraSettingItem[] cameraSettingItems = new CameraSettingItem[]
            {
                new  CameraSettingItem { Id = ShutterSpeedDefaultValue, Description = string.Empty},
                new  CameraSettingItem {Id = 1, Description = "30" + secNotationPostfix}
            };

Comment: 2nd suggestion is good enough, private member variable as array and in the end .ToList(); Code from 354 lines to 3 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can store items that you need in JSON or XML files and deserialize them when you need using [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) for example:

```
public static SelectList CreateShutterSpeedList(
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(@"\ShutterSpeedList.json");
    var shutterSpeedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CameraSettingItem>>(json);
    // Convert shutterSpeedList to SelectList and return
}
```

Alternatively you can reduce number of lines by using collection initializer (as @dasblinkenlight pointed out) and constructors with optional parameters/object initializers if you have access to `CameraSettingItem` code:

```
public static SelectList CreateShutterSpeedList()
{
    var secNotationPostfix = "\"";    
    var shutterSpeedList = new List<CameraSettingItem>
    {
        new CameraSettingItem(id: ShutterSpeedDefaultValue),
        new CameraSettingItem(id: 1, description: "30" + secNotationPostfix),
        ...
    };
    // Convert shutterSpeedList to SelectList and return
}
```